# Error in USB Communication - Android Development

Tags: java

I'm studying android communication by USB and I'm developing a very simple app for me to understand the basic concept of USB communication. The function of the app and display in Text View the information of the device connected to the USB of the tablet by clicking the button ( Check USB Device ), but by pressing the button the app closes alone.
I need help and guidance regarding the error that is occurring in my app, if anyone can help me locate and detect the error will help me a lot and will be very important to my learning. From now on I thank you

***if anyone can keep up with my evolution according to my post here, lambent will be cool.***

Download App to Test - Google Drive

[Download App Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qHrDy_0D2dWqlNX8io10geUZonyrF5St/view)

*Screen Design*

[Screen Design - Click Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8frB.png)

**NullPointerException**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.android.usb, PID: 7074
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.android.usb.MainActivity.checkInfo(MainActivity.java:80)
        at com.android.usb.MainActivity.access$000(MainActivity.java:25)
        at com.android.usb.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:44)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**Logcat**

```
09-07 10:49:10.170 6370-6370/com.android.usb D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
09-07 10:49:10.170 6370-6370/com.android.usb W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x415d3ba8)
09-07 10:49:10.170 6370-6370/com.android.usb E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.android.usb, PID: 6370
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.android.usb.MainActivity.checkInfo(MainActivity.java:81)
        at com.android.usb.MainActivity.access$000(MainActivity.java:25)
        at com.android.usb.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:44)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**acticity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/check"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Check USB Device" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/info"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="677dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.android.usb">

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.usb.host" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**MainActiviry.java**

```
package com.android.usb;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.hardware.usb.UsbDevice;
import android.hardware.usb.UsbManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String ACTION_USB_PERMISSION = "com.android.usb.USB_PERMISSION";
    Button btnCheck;
    TextView textInfo;
    UsbManager usbManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button btnCheck = (Button) findViewById(R.id.check);
        final TextView textInfo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.info);
        btnCheck.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0)
            {
                textInfo.setText("");
                checkInfo();
            }
        });

    }

    private void checkInfo()
    {
        UsbManager manager = (UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
        
        /*------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

        PendingIntent permissionIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION), 0);
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION);
        registerReceiver(usbReceiver, filter);
        
        /*------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

        HashMap<String, UsbDevice> deviceList = manager.getDeviceList();
        Iterator<UsbDevice> deviceIterator = deviceList.values().iterator();
        String i = "";
        while(deviceIterator.hasNext())
        {
            UsbDevice device = deviceIterator.next();

            /*------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

            usbManager.requestPermission(device, permissionIntent);
            i += "\n" + "DeviceID: " + device.getDeviceId() + "\n"
                    + "DeviceName: " + device.getDeviceName() + "\n"
                    + "DeviceClass: " + device.getDeviceClass() + " - "
                    + "DeviceSubClass: " + device.getDeviceSubclass() + "\n"
                    + "VendorID: " + device.getVendorId() + "\n"
                    + "ProductID: " + device.getProductId() + "\n";
        }

        textInfo.setText(i);

    }

    /*------------------------------------------------------*/

    private final BroadcastReceiver usbReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver()
    {

        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (ACTION_USB_PERMISSION.equals(action))
            {
                synchronized (this)
                {
                    UsbDevice device = (UsbDevice)intent.getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_DEVICE);

                    if (intent.getBooleanExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_PERMISSION_GRANTED, false))
                    {
                        if(device != null)
                        {
                            //call method to set up device communication
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Log.d("ERROR", "permission denied for device " + device);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };
    
    /*------------------------------------------------------*/
    
}
```

Thank You

Comment: I checked your MailActivity.java but for me line 81 is an empty line. Your Stacktrace and your MainActivity does not match. Can you please give us a hint which in which line the NullPointerException appears?

Comment: Hi, I added the NullPointerException in the question post, if you need any more information, let me know that I'll added to the question post so i can help other people.  ok and Thank You

Comment: Yeah, I have seen the Exception in your post. But when I copy the code of your posted MainActivity.java to my editor to see which line of code is in line 81 I only see an empty line. Which means I can not see what causes the error. Please open Android Studio and tell me, what code is in Line 81. Because Line 81 causes the exception.

Comment: Yes, I only see an empty line too, I'll make the download of the app I'm developing available, so you can see what I'm seeing here. I think this will help you save time. The link is on the post.

Comment: I managed to solve the problem of the app closing alone, but now I'm with another problem. I will answer my own question and post the new code and the new problem.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem of the app closing, the problem it was in the TextView statement before onCreate(). Now I'm having a new problem, I run the app on my tablet and plug something into the serial port, but nothing happens, it should display the device information, but it does not happen and the tablet does not display the dialog requesting authorization for connection; What must be wrong with my code?

**MainAcivity.java - ( **app closing Fixed** )**

```
package com.android.usb;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.hardware.usb.UsbDevice;
import android.hardware.usb.UsbManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String ACTION_USB_PERMISSION = "com.android.usb.USB_PERMISSION";
    Button btnCheck;
    TextView textInfo;
    UsbManager usbManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btnCheck = (Button) findViewById(R.id.check);
        textInfo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.info);
        btnCheck.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0)
            {
                textInfo.setText("");
                checkInfo();
            }
        });

    }

    private void checkInfo()
    {
        UsbManager manager = (UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);

        PendingIntent permissionIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION), 0);
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION);
        registerReceiver(usbReceiver, filter);

        HashMap<String, UsbDevice> deviceList = manager.getDeviceList();
        Iterator<UsbDevice> deviceIterator = deviceList.values().iterator();
        String i = "";
        while(deviceIterator.hasNext())
        {
            UsbDevice device = deviceIterator.next();

            usbManager.requestPermission(device, permissionIntent);
            i += "\n" + "DeviceID: " + device.getDeviceId() + "\n"
                    + "DeviceName: " + device.getDeviceName() + "\n"
                    + "DeviceClass: " + device.getDeviceClass() + " - "
                    + "DeviceSubClass: " + device.getDeviceSubclass() + "\n"
                    + "VendorID: " + device.getVendorId() + "\n"
                    + "ProductID: " + device.getProductId() + "\n";
        }

        textInfo.setText(i);
    }

    /*---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

    private final BroadcastReceiver usbReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver()
    {

        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (ACTION_USB_PERMISSION.equals(action))
            {
                synchronized (this)
                {
                    UsbDevice device = (UsbDevice)intent.getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                    /*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

                    if (intent.getBooleanExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_PERMISSION_GRANTED, false))
                    {
                        if(device != null)
                        {
                            //call method to set up device communication
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Log.d("ERROR", "permission denied for device " + device);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };
    /*------------------------------------------------------*/
}
```

Thank You again

Comment: This can have several causes: Do you has added the Intent-Filter to the Manifest? Do has granted the rights correctly? etc.  Check out his Android Documentation which is really helpful for working with USB: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host#java